# How do I load every section of a JSON file that has objects of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My JSON file looks like the following:

```
[{ "articles": [
    { "1": { "sections":
            [ {"1": "Lots of stuff here."} ]
        }
    },
    { "2": { "sections":
            [ {"1": "And some more text right here"} ]
        }
    }
}]
```

The basic premise is that it has one element in the overall array called `"articles"`, which is equal to an array of `"sections"`.

In other words, it's a constitution, so it looks like this:

Article X

-Section A

-Section B

-Section C

Article Z

...

I want to be able to pull out each article and load it into

```
<div class="alert text-black" id="article">
  <p class="lead" id="articleHeader"><strong>Article 1</strong></p>
  <dl>
    <dt id="article_section">Section 1</dt>
    <dd id="article_sectionINFO">this stuff belongs to section 1</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

and this is the script I have so far:

```
var loadEvents = function(d){
$.each(d, function(i){
  var articleN = i;
  var articleID = "article" + i;
  var articleHeaderID = "articleHeader" + i;
  var articleHeader = "<p class='lead' id='articleHeader'><strong>Article " + i + "</strong></p>";
  var mySections = new Array();
  $.each(d, function(i){
    var sectionN = i;
    var sectionID = "article" + articleN + "section" + sectionN;
    var sectionINFO = sectionID + "INFO";
    mySections[k] =
    "<dt id='" + sectionID +"'> Section " + sectionN + "</dt>" +
    "<dd id='" + sectionINFO +"'>" + d[sectionN].
  })
  $("#eventHolder").append(new_block(articleID, articleHeaderID, articleHeader)); //to call the new element
})}

$.getJSON('data/constitution.json', loadConstitution);
```

Basically, I just want to be able to reproduce a larger box (as shown in the `<html>` code above) for each article, with a list (`<dl></dl>`) for each section. How do I access the data from the JSON file correctly?

Comment: how can an incomplete question get upvoted?

Comment: @starskythehutch I guess some people just glance, see theres code posted and go "yep! that's good!" :(

Comment: It cut off the last part of my question for some reason. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have an array that contains an object that contains the `article` property that is an array that contains articles, you need to get down to that property to loop through them. Use two properties in the callback function so that you can access the article object:

```
$.each(d[0].articles, function(i, article) {
```

As each item is an object that contains a `sections` property that is an array that contains the sections, you need to get down to that property in each item. Use a different index variable for the sections, so that you still can access the `i` variable used for the article index:

```
var mySections = article.sections;
$.each(mySections, function(j, section) {
```

Inside that loop, `j` is the index of the section, `section` is the section string, and `i` is still then index of the article.

That should get you on the right track with the looping, the rest is mostly just using the right variable for each value.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I'd access the section data? Is it `d[j]` or `mySections[j]`?

Comment: @Luxelin: You would access it using `mySections[j]` or simply `section`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dinuR9kR I used the same HTML as shown above and the same JSON file, but this isn't working. you can ignore line 31: document.write(thisSection);

Comment: @Luxelin: I don't see any errors in the code. What happens when you try it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: No, there aren't any errors in the debugger/console thing. Just nothing shows up other than the template I wrote above.

Comment: @Luxelin: An id should be unique in the page, and they won't be that any more when you clone it. Use classes to specify the containers in the template.