# How do I load the elements of an array inside of an object in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I asked a similar (but different) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247503/how-do-i-load-every-section-of-a-json-file-that-has-objects-of-objects) before.

I've since changed how I'm approaching the problem.

[This](http://pastebin.com/HtgZZBtk) is my JSON file.

Here's my javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loadArticle = function (articleID, articleH) {
        var article = $("#article").clone();
        var thelist = '<dl id="article' + articleID + 'sections"></dl>';

        $(article).attr("id", "article" + articleID);
        $(article).append(articleH);
        $(article).html(thelist);

        return article;
    }
    var loadSection = function (articleID, sectionID, sectionContent) {
        var section = "#article" + articleID + "sections";

        $(section).append("<dt>Section " + sectionID + "</dt>");
        $(section).append("<dd>" + sectionContent + "</dd>");

        return section;
    }
    var loadConstitution = function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (i) {
            var articleID = i + 1;
            var articleH = "<p class='lead' id='article" + articleID + "'><strong>Article " + articleID + "</strong></p>";
            $("#constitutionHolder").append(loadArticle(articleID, articleH));

            //$.each(d.sections, function(j){
            //  var sectionID = j + 1;
            //  var theSection = d.sections[j];
            //$("#article" + articleID + "sections").append(articleID, sectionID, mySection);
            //})
        })
    }
    $.getJSON('data/stuff.json', loadConstitution);
})
```

Basically, I go through each data point and make a new `<div>` with the `id="article1"`(or whatever the number of the article may be). Then, since each article object is filled with one array of `"sections"`, I need to access the data in this array and append it to the `<dl></dl>` I have.

In my HTML, this is what I'm `.clone()`ing:

```
<div id="constitutionHolder">
    <div class="alert text-black" id="article">
        <p class="lead" id="articleHeader"><strong>Article 1</strong>
        </p>
        <dl id="sectionList"> <dt id="article_section">Section 1</dt>
            <dd id="article_sectionINFO">this stuff belongs to section 1</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 problems so far:

1. `$(article).append(articleH);` isn't working
2. I can't load the sections into `sectionList`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: please indent your code so it's easy to understand what lives in which scope.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I don't think I can make a jsfiddle since I'm using a JSON file (unless I can copy the entire JSON file into the javascript portion).

Comment: that's all you have to do... `var data= /* paste here*/`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/psquared/JqxAw/.  I don't understand what you're trying to do though.  If you comment out line 8 in the fiddle and look at the DOM, it looks odd to me.

Comment: I'm trying to make a `<div class="alert...">` for each article, and a `<dt></dt><dd></dd>` for each `"section"`. The section stuff is the data from the JSON file in quotes.

Comment: Is this what you're aiming for?  I stripped out all the noise: http://jsfiddle.net/psquared/JqxAw/2/

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect. I'll just adapt that for an external JSON file. If you add it as an answer below, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to approach this, but here's an example that you might be able to modify to suit your application: http://jsfiddle.net/DgU3w/.  (Note that I stripped out some details to try to understand the problem)

A few things I noticed in your example:

- `loadArticle()` clobbers some work with this statement: `$(article).html(thelist);`
- `loadArticle()` clones a block of HTML, but then it appends new elements that match cloned ones.
- It doesn't hurt to wrap jQuery objects (e.g. `$(jQueryObj)`), but it's not necessary either.
- Some IDs were initialized to unique values, but others weren't.

Comment: I put it up on my math club's [website](http://gablesmao.com) under the info page. Works great. Thanks!